# BigInt isPrime test, more elegant solution?

Tags: scala, biginteger

Is this the most elegant way to express a `isPrime` function for `BigInt` objects?

Here's what I have for regular integers:

```
  def isPrimeForInt(n: Int): Boolean = {
    val ceiling = math.sqrt(n.toDouble).toInt
    (2 until ceiling) forall (x => n % x != 0)
  }
```

Here's what I have for BigInts:

```
  def isPrimeForBigInt(n: BigInt): Boolean = {
    def ceiling: BigInt = {
      def f(a: BigInt): Stream[BigInt] = a #:: f(a+1)
      f(BigInt(1)).dropWhile(_.pow(2) < n)(0)
    }
    Range.BigInt(BigInt(2), ceiling , BigInt(1)) forall (x => n % x != 0)
  }
```

Comment: Is this for an actual primality tester? 'Cause if it is and you actually need arbitrary precision for the numbers you'll be testing, then only the probabilistic primality-testing algorithms are feasible.

Comment: @Randall this is a primality tester for java BigIntegers

Comment: Then I recommend you learn about tractable probabilistic primality testing for large integers. Also, I'd convert the Java BigInteger to Scala BigInt, do the work and then convert back to return the Java BigInteger.

Comment: @Randall correction, for scala BigInt (I assumed BigInt is a scala implementation of Java BigInteger, but I should have been more precise).

Comment: for big integersyou should use MillerRabin test http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test. It takes way less than second to test 10^700 + 7. Only disadvantage is that it is probablistic and can yield false positive, but that is small probabilty and can be avoided with correct implementation.

Comment: You can use the build in probabilistic tester: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#isProbablePrime(int)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my primality checker for BigInts:

```
private static Boolean isSpsp(BigInteger n, BigInteger a)
{
    BigInteger two = BigInteger.valueOf(2);
    BigInteger n1 = n.subtract(BigInteger.ONE);
    BigInteger d = n1;
    int s = 0;

    while (d.mod(two).equals(BigInteger.ZERO))
    {
        d = d.divide(two);
        s += 1;
    }

    BigInteger t = a.modPow(d, n);

    if (t.equals(BigInteger.ONE) || t.equals(n1))
    {
        return true;
    }

    while (--s > 0)
    {
        t = t.multiply(t).mod(n);
        if (t.equals(n1))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

public static Boolean isPrime(BigInteger n)
{
    Random r = new Random();
    BigInteger two = BigInteger.valueOf(2);
    BigInteger n3 = n.subtract(BigInteger.valueOf(3));
    BigInteger a;
    int k = 25;

    if (n.compareTo(two) < 0)
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (n.mod(two).equals(BigInteger.ZERO))
    {
        return n.equals(two);
    }

    while (k > 0)
    {
        a = new BigInteger(n.bitLength(), r).add(two);
        while (a.compareTo(n) >= 0)
        {
            a = new BigInteger(n.bitLength(), r).add(two);
        }

        if (! isSpsp(n, a))
        {
            return false;
        }

        k -= 1;
    }

    return true;
}
```

You can read more about it at my [Programming with Prime Numbers](http://programmingpraxis.com/essays/) essay.

Answer (score 1):

You change `Int` for `BigInt` in your first example. Why are you rewriting it?

Comment: Because he wants to compute primes, that exceed 2147483647 (Int.MaxValue)? (But maybe there is a place for Long).

Comment: Since the OP is taking the square root, it works up to 64-bit integer range. Then arguably there is no point in trying to iterate over a range greater than `0x7FFFFFFF` to check for divisibility. My guess was that the OP just happens to have `BigInt`s but doesn't want to compute primes with 1000 digits.

Comment: @Alex - but then `Long` is sufficient

Comment: @0__ thank you!! ... but still, I'm curious about what this would look like with big integers.